# RabbitMQ does not load the advanced.config file

Tags: rabbitmq

We are looking to upgrade to the latest version of RabbitMQ so I have installed Erlang 24.0 and RabbitMQ 3.8.16 onto a Windows 10 PC for testing. I have the two RabbitMQ configuration files (rabbitmq.conf and advanced.config) stored in a folder called C:\RabbitMQ. The advanced.config contains static shovel configuration. I cannot get RabbitMQ to recognise the advanced.config file. Has anyone encountered this problem before?

We have earlier installs of RabbitMQ (i.e. Erlang 22.1 an RabbitMQ 3.8.2) running on Windows Server 2019 and these earlier versions load both config files with no issues.

All of our RabbitMQ installations store the config files in a folder called C:\RabbitMQ. We then set three environment variables to ensure that RabbitMQ recognises the folder and files:

- RABBITMQ_ADVANCED_CONFIG_FILE - C:\RabbitMQ\advanced
- RABBITMQ_BASE - C:\RabbitMQ
- RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE - C:\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq

I have followed the advice on the RabbitMQ config page https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html with regard to verifying the config file location.

I have also run the rabbitmq-diagnostics command which shows that only one config file is being loaded:

[image]

If I run the same command on our earlier installation then I can see that both files are being loaded:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We tested it internally and everything works as expected.

Note that:

```
RABBITMQ_ADVANCED_CONFIG_FILE=/path/to/a/custom/location/advanced.config
```

you need to add `.config`

see:

```
RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE=/path/to/a/custom/location/rabbitmq.conf

# overrides advanced config file location
RABBITMQ_ADVANCED_CONFIG_FILE=/path/to/a/custom/location/advanced.config
```

here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the problem. It looks like we have been incorrectly setting the environment variables on all of our RabbitMQ installations. Interestingly, our earlier installations which run RabbitMQ 3.8.2 correctly picked up the configuration files even though we were not including the config file extensions in the environment variables.